# How To Create Custom Cell Style For DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my data grid view I applied a custom cell style which can be able to convert double numbers in to 2 digit version 
ex: 10,12356 => 10,12.

```
dataGridView.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0,00";
```

My question is that how can I add the "%" sign next to the formatted number like 
ex: %10,12

I have already tried this

```
dataGridView.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "%0,00";
```

but I obtained %10,12356 not %10,12

Comment: It requires escaping `= "\\%0.00";`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Use a dot (`.`), not a comma, as the decimal separator. + Set your Column's data type to `decimal`. + If you don't escape it, you'll get weird values.